# Why Are Modification Logs Misleading?

Tags: support

I noticed something odd going on. Two questions I found interesting on the front page list new modification (incidentally both by [Abraham Ray](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/30985/abraham-ray)). So of course I wanted to read what was edited.

[image: Listed modifications]

Clicking the links, they lead me to the main pages of each question. So OK, that implies the modifications are in the OP. But when I look at the modification logs, neither [of](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/141899/revisions) [them](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/140725/revisions) has any modifications by Abraham Ray, not even reverted ones!

What's going on with the logs? It looks like a bug (incorrect display of what is the last modification), but maybe it's something else?

Comment: What page is this screenshot from? Is it from the questions list, when viewing "active"?

Comment: It's from just opening the https://rpg.stackexchange.com/ link, which indeed leads to the Active tab. (I have some of the common tags filtered out, so these questions are currently on the first page for me.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### This user has a now deleted answer in both questions

I found those same questions in the list of active questions, and clicking on the "modified x hours ago" on each of them did bring me directly to these now deleted answers.

Since you [need 10k reputation to view deleted posts](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) that is probably why you were simply directed to the main post.

There is also a [request on the main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70024/when-an-answer-is-deleted-change-person-listed-as-last-modifier) to change this behavior and the [same question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75828/last-activity-on-question-shows-modified-by-user-who-did-not-ask-or-answer?noredirect=1&lq=1) also asked on the main meta.

Comment: OK, so why is the deleted *modification* shown to me if I'm not supposed to see deleted things?

Comment: The modification shows up because it did happen. The same front page gets shown to everyone with or without deletion privileges. It's not ideal, it's a compromise thing. But hey, now you know how to tell when something got deleted. :P

Comment: The same sort of thing happens if one follows a link to a now-deleted comment. (Those are rather rarer, but it happens, and took me a while to figure out.)

Comment: There is also a technical aspect here: the thing that snaps you to a particular location in the page is the `#` string in the URL, which is interpreted by browsers to go find the matching anchor in the page. If there is no match, the browser just keeps you on the top of the page. So when a deleted answer (or comment) isn’t on the page, there is nothing to jump to, and the browser just does nothing—which is the same behavior we have for going to the question.