# How was this question bumped to the top of the home page?

Tags: discussion, editing

"[How many times do you roll damage for Magic Missile?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/109764/how-many-times-do-you-roll-damage-for-magic-missile)" was bumped to the top of the home page today, and a note underneath the question on the home page states that it was modified today by mattdm. But the change logs of the question and both answers do not indicate any edits today. So what was changed exactly?

Comment: Related: [Why Are Modification Logs Misleading?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8826/why-are-modification-logs-misleading/)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There’s [a deleted answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/147580/321) (10k+ rep only) that someone else posted four hours ago, and which was deleted three hours ago.

mattdm made an edit to two hours ago to fix problems with the answer.

This is confusing until you get the 10k privilege to see deleted answers, but it’s not really avoidable: when it was first bumped it was visible, and needed the bump to highlight the new activity, which needed attention and got it deleted. The delete made the source of the first and second bumps invisible, and there’s no “unbump” feature. This is by design, since 10k users still need activity on deleted posts highlighted, in order to do oversight.

In this case, since the edit was made to try to fix the problems that got the post deleted, it particularly needs the visibility to users who have undelete vote privileges, so they can judge if those votes should be cast.